# who is responsible for symbolic reference linker or loader

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, compiler-construction, linker, loader

I have read a lot of article about linker or loader but
I am confuse who is responsible to replace absolute reference in an object module by symbolic  references to location in other object modules.
Does linker replace symbolic reference in other object module or loader make this at program loading time in main memory

Comment: you should be able to see this experimentally.  The object (assembler/compiler) is responsible for placing symbolic names for things it needs/has.  the linker will also add some symbolic names, certainly for items defined in the linker script, and the linker is the only one that can globally connect the dots between objects, so if one object has an extern and another contains that item the linker places the item and updates both as it links them together.

Comment: not sure where the loader comes in on this, that is a bit late to be defining things

Comment: please provide an example of a data item and its symbols in the object and binary that you are interested in.  Provide an example basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolving symbol dependencies between object modules has traditionally been the responsibility of the linker. The linker examines all object files and resolves all symbolic references and builds a monolithic executable. However, this approach breaks down when we introduce shared libraries, i.e. object modules that can be shared between different executables and that are linked to the program at load time. To make this work some parts of the linker is moved into the loader, making the resolution of dependencies as shared responsibility. The linker resolves dependencies between the object files and static libraries while the loader resolves dependencies between the executable and any shared library.